# Why are $R^2$ values not available in mixed effects meta regressions

Tags: r, meta-analysis, meta-regression, metafor, meta-learning

I'm currently conducting a meta-regression for my predictors from a meta-analysis of proportion. In calculating the mixed effects meta-regressions, I wanted to identify how much heterogeneity is accounted for when a predictor is considered in the model. To do this, I used the `meta` package with a `metareg` function in R: `m.prop.reg <- metareg(m.prop, ~PublicationYear)`
The output provides out $I^2$ and $H^2$ values as well as the significance of our moderators, however, it does not provide an $R^2$ value for the amount of heterogeneity accounted for.

My question is how can I get $R^2$ for my predictors.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Are you sure that an $R^2$-style metric would even give the proportion of variance accounted for? That is only the interpretation in specific situations, and I am not sure that a mixed model is such a situation.